# Null Space of Matrix (Linear Algebra)

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces, linear-transformations, matrix-decomposition

I have the problem in understanding some particular case of Null Space Matrix

1. Given (3x3 Matrix) RREF (A) =
   $$\pmatrix{0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 & 0}$$
   Why the vector of the null space is $$\pmatrix{1 \\ 0 \\ 0}$$

instead of all zero? we know that x2 = 0, x3 = 0

Comment: MathJax tip: To write$$\pmatrix{a & b & c \\ d & e & f \\ g & h & i},$$you can type `$$\pmatrix{a & b & c \\ d & e & f \\ g & h & i}$$`. Column vectors are simple too: `$$\pmatrix{a \\ b \\ c}$$` produces$$\pmatrix{a \\ b \\ c}$$Check out more of this stuff in the [MathJax Tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference), particularly the first "answer" about formatting matrices.

Comment: Thank you very much for correcting my writing format, it helps a lot

Comment: When you multiply any three by three matrix by that vector you pick out the first column. Try it.

Comment: My pleasure. Thank you for editing your question. I've done a little extra touch-up too. If you want to see how I've done it (e.g. how to inline equations, or making subscripts like $x_2$ and $x_3$), you can just press [edit], and even play around with the code.

Comment: The null space of a fixed matrix is a *set*, or *collection* of some vectors. So $\pmatrix{1 \\ 0 \\ 0}$ and $\pmatrix{0 \\ 0 \\ 0}$ can both be members of the null space of $A$.

Comment: thanks everyone for helping me through out the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at the definition of [null space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel_(linear_algebra)) (kernel is just a synonym) of a matrix $A$: it's the *set of all vectors* $x$ such that $Ax=0$  (here, $0$ denotes the all-zero vector). More specifically, and without being too rigorous, the null space $\operatorname{ker}(A)$ is a vector space:

- $0 \in \operatorname{ker}(A)$, since $A\cdot 0 = 0$;
- if $x, y \in \operatorname{ker}(A)$, then $ax + by \in \operatorname{ker}(A)$, for all $a,b \in \mathbb{R}$ (I'm assuming your matrix has real entries, but you can extend the result to other fields): indeed $A(ax+by) = aAx + bAy = a\cdot 0 + b \cdot 0 = 0$.

Once you get more familiar with the theory (the link above is a good starting point), you will see that the null space of your matrix is just
$$
\operatorname{ker}(A)=\left\{a\pmatrix{1\\0\\0} : a\in \mathbb{R}\right\}
$$
and we say that the null space has dimension 1. And, of course, the null vector is part of it.